# How to force Quickly to NOT include a dependency? (Specifically: apport)

Tags: application-development, quickly, dependencies, packaging, apport

My case is this - the quickly-generated application contains some apport code, so quickly inserts `python-apport` in the dependencies list. I would like the application to be installable and run on Linux Mint as well, where this package is missing. I would like to wrap the apport code in a `try/except ImportError` section, so that it is optional, and therefore python-apport would be better in the Suggests or Recommends section of the debian control file (not sure what the difference is between Suggests and Recommends), and not in Depends.

How can I do this?

If this is not possible, what are the implications if I completely remove the generated apport folder and the apport-dependent code in it?

```
def add_info(report):
    """add report info"""

    if not apport.packaging.is_distro_package(report['Package'].split()[0]):
        report['ThirdParty'] = 'True'
        report['CrashDB'] = 'variety'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the 'variety' CrashDB is exactly, but without the third party check there, and your application not being in Ubuntu proper, it means apport won't be usable to report bugs for your application.

Whether this is an issue or not, is something you need to decide. If it's not an issue, then the apport bits should be safe to remove.

You can also simply edit the generated debian/control file, and move the python-apport dependency from the Depends: field and into the Suggests: field.